# How do I ask "Can we speak German between us?"

Tags: grammar

I'm learning German and I'd like to ask my friend "Can we speak German between us?".

I wrote the following sentence to him but I'm not sure I was right:

> Können wir Deutsch sprechen mit uns?

Is this correct?

Comment: "mit uns" => "miteinander", then it's OK

Answer (score 9):

"Können wir deutsch sprechen?" or "Können wir auf deutsch miteinander reden?" would be valid solutions. The "mit uns" sounds weird to me.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize "between us" because we regularly speak english when other people are around and also when we're together. So I just realized what I'd like to say is "Can we speak german when we talk to each other?"

Comment: So you've got a friend who is also able to speak german, and want to tell him something, that's not for everyones ears? Why don't you just start talking German? You might also say "Können wir deutsch spechen, wenn wir miteinander reden?"

Comment: No, I just want to speak german with him when we're together to improve my german language skills. :) It doesn't matter if other people hear us. It's just I'd like to propose this possibility of always talking german when we're together.

Comment: All the solutions I mentioned work. Or you might ask in english. :P

Comment: "Können wir uns auf deutsch unterhalten?" is Ok, too.

Comment: I think the „auf“ in „Können wir auf deutsch miteinander reden?“ should not be there.

Comment: That's possible, too

Comment: Instead of trying to emphasize *between us* by finding a slightly better translation, you could just give more context: `Können wir Deutsch reden, wenn die anderen nicht dabei sind? Ich möchte mein Deutsch üben.`

Answer (score 7):

It is perfectly sufficient to say (or write):

> Können wir Deutsch sprechen?

As a native speaker I see no need to translate the "between us", but if you want explicitly to translate the "between us"-part, the correct preposition would be "zwischen" or "unter" i.e.

> "Können wir unter/zwischen uns Deutsch sprechen?"

One possible variant would be the use of "könnten wir..." instead of "können wir..." (so called *Konjunktiv II*), which sounds a bit more polite.
One further (minor) correction: The umlaut-dots are mandatory in "wir können". If you cannot type them with your keyboard and don't want to use unicode, the correct thing to type is "oe" for "ö".

Comment: _Zwischen uns_ sounds very strange to me, and _unter uns_ hardly better. If there has to be some phrase like that, I'd prefer _untereinander_.

Comment: I second that „zwischen uns“ is wrong and also that „untereinander“ is preferable, even though I would have no problem with „Können wir deutsch reden, wenn wir unter uns sind?“

Comment: Thomas, you're doing it again....

Answer (score 4):

**No, it is not.**

You'd use e. g.

> Können wir [auf/in Deutsch] deutsch **miteinander** reden?

*If* you want to use a preposition, you might prefer `auf` over `in` and note that in this case `Deutsch` comes with a capital because it is used "*im Sinne von »deutsche Sprache«*"  ([Regel 72](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch)).

Basically it'd suficcient to say

> Können wir deutsch sprechen?

But using `miteinander` emphasizes that it's about you and your dialog partner.

---

Note

`wir ... mit uns` does work in German, but has a different sense. In German when using pronouns together which refer to the same person or group of persons, it has always a reflexive sense and thus to be used like that.

> Können wir deutsch mit uns [selbst] sprechen ?
>   <sub>the predicate comes last</sub>

In this case both (`wir` and `uns`) is 1st person plural. One does not have to put `selbst`, but without it will be even less comprehensible. It would mean something like

> Can we talk German to ourselves?
>   <sub>as in
>
>   Some people are in a room practising talking to themselves in different languages and from while to while the language is switched by somebody asking: "Can we talk German to ourselves [now]?"</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker I'd say "Können wir uns auf Deutsch unterhalten?" or "Können wir auf Deutsch (miteinander) reden?" if you want to use the verb *reden*. The first question is more usual.