# Preposition for "in/auf einer Sprache unterhalten"

Tags: usage, preposition

> Wir können zwischen uns Deutsch sprechen
>
> Wir können uns **_____** Deutsch unterhalten.

Should I use "auf" or "in" here? In English we would use "in" with a language, but here I suspect it would be "auf". Is there any case where we would use "in Deutsch"?

Comment: "zwischen uns" finde ich falsch, aber man kann sagen "wir können miteinander deutsch sprechen"

Comment: Related: [How do I ask “Can we speak German between us?”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-do-i-ask-can-we-speak-german-between-us)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible, but I think, that `auf` is more common than `in`. And that's backed by [ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20Deutsch%20unterhalten,%20auf%20Deutsch%20unterhalten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,in%20Deutsch%20unterhalten;,c0;.t1;,auf%20Deutsch%20unterhalten;,c0)

Comment: Ich empfinde "in" als falsch. Das ngram wird deutlicher, wenn Du den Haken bei case-insensitive setzt.

Comment: Das ngram wird deutlicher. Das stimmt.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for "auf". "Sich in Sprache X unterhalten" sounds like an awkward machine-translation from English, to be honest.

Another option would be - although it sounds a bit formal - to leave out the prepositions: "Wir können uns deutsch unterhalten." I wouldn't recommend that, though.

Comment: "deutsch unterhalten" sounds like "in a German manner", not like "using the German language".